# Validation for elements added on runtime

Tags: php, jquery, html, validation

I am using the following script to add image input fields to my webpage. Everything is working fine, but what if I want to do the validation. I dont want to submit the form if any of the fields are empty. I tried the code i.e function `validate()` but it only checks for the first input field, i.e the input field of html. It doesnot work for the input fields added in runtime with the help of Jquery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate () {
            var file = document.getElementById('file').value;
            if(file==""){
                alert("None of the Image Fields can be empty!!");
            return false;
            }
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){ 

      $('#addproduct').click(function(){                
        $(this).after('<br /><input type="file" name="image_name[]" class="addfile" id="file" /> <input type="text" name="image_caption[]" placeholder="Caption for this image " size="60" /> ');
      });       
    });

    </script>
```

And I would like to add the delete functionality for the image fields. Like a cross button beside every input field, and the field be removed when clicked on that button.

```
<input type="file" name="image_name[]" id="file" required="true"> 
<input type="text" name="image_caption[]" placeholder="Caption for this image "  size="60">
<span id="addproduct"></span>
```

Comment: In a jQuery environment, you should not use `document.getElementById`, nor you should be generating inline HTML like that - create DOM elements via jQuery and pass them parameters to keep your code more maintainable!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `document.getElementById('file')` use `document.getElementsByName('image_name[]')` or jQuery style `$('[name="image_name[]"]')`. This is because the `id` of a tag must be unique, else only the first one can be referenced by `id`.

For the delete functionality use something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

  $('#addproduct').click(function(){                
    $(this).after('<br /><div><input type="file" name="image_name[]" class="addfile" id="file" /> <input type="text" name="image_caption[]" placeholder="Caption for this image " size="60" /> <input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)" /> </div>');
  });       
});

var deleteRow = function(elem) {
    $(elem).parent().remove();
}
```